# Seeking a combinatorial proof for $2^n-1=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{n-k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The hint says: the LHS counts nonempty subsets of $\{1, \dots , n\}$. If you get stuck, try to do a small example, say $n = 4$. Try to classify these sets in a way that splits them into classes of size $2^3$, $2^2$, $2^1$, and $2^0$.

I get stuck with how to classify these sets.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple proof by induction?

Comment: This is the art of combinatorics. In some ways a double counting argument is much more elegant than brute force induction. Remember, when the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:  How many subsets include $1$?  How many *don't* include $1$ but *do* include $2$?  How many don't include $1$ or $2$ but do include $3$? Etc.